# Как вставить данные в таблицу а при совпадении определенных полей обновить всю строку?

Tags: php, sql, массивы

Есть таблица списка материалов, пользователи перетаскиванием определяют их веса

Вес должен сохраняться для каждого пользователя индивидуально, для этого создал таблицу как на картинке.

Тип СУБД: MySQL

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить в нее данные из массива, а если есть совпадения по паре полей **id пользователя/id материала** обновить эту строку

ниже массив который приходят от пользователя 1, в который добавился элемент с ключем 3

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        uid => 1,
        nid => 4545,
        weight=>1,
    ),
    1 => array(
        uid => 1,
        nid => 54878,
        weight=>2,
    ),
    2 => array(
        uid => 1,
        nid => 2,
        weight=>3,
    ),
    3 => array(
        uid => 1,
        nid => 5,
        weight=>4,
    ),
    4 => array(
        uid => 1,
        nid => 15,
        weight=>5,
    ),      
)
```

- uid - id пользователя
- nid - id материала

вот скрин структуры таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Как добавить в нее данные из массива, а если есть совпадения по паре полей id пользователя/id материала обновить эту строку* 1) Добавить уникальный индекс по `(id пользователя/id материала)` - это обязательно, если запрос по п. 2 для Вашей СУБД не поддерживает произвольное условие конфликта в запросе, иначе желательно (непротиворечивость данных надо поддерживать). 2) Воспользоваться соответствующим запросом (СУБД Вы указать не удосужились), который при конфликте при вставке новой записи обновляет существующую (например, для MySQL это будет `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` или `REPLACE`).

Comment: @Akina дополнил вопрос. вот так на словах из комментария сложно понять, поэтому и задал вопрос на форуме, чтобы, может быть кто то написал вомзможный пример

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте ещё CREATE TABLE таблицы-источника.

Comment: @Akina добавил скрин, не знаю, то не то...

Comment: То, но не так. Надо было выполнить запрос `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` и поместить сюда полученный текст вывода (без обрамления). Кстати, в структуре не видны внешние ключи на таблицы пользователей и материалов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим:

1) Таблица имеет такую структуру:

```
CREATE TABLE material_weights (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
mat_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
usr_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
weight INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
FOREIGN KEY (mat_id) REFERENCES materials (id),
FOREIGN KEY (usr_id) REFERENCES userss (id) )
```

2) Данные передаются в виде группы (или групп) формата (new_mat_id, new_use_id, new_weight).

Тогда нужно:

1) Создать требуемый индекс (предварительно проверив, что в данных нет противоречащих ему дубликатов)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_mat_usr ON material_weights (mat_id, usr_id)
```

2) Выполнять вставку данных запросом

```
INSERT INTO material_weights (mat_id, usr_id, weight)
VALUES (@new_mat_id, @new_use_id, @new_weight)
/*   , (@new_mat_id2, @new_use_id2, @new_weight2), ... */
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = VALUES(weight)
```

Что делает этот запрос?

Если вставляемая пара (mat_id, usr_id) в таблице отсутствует, нарушения уникального индекса не возникает, и запись вставляется обычным образом.

Если вставляемая пара (mat_id, usr_id) в таблице присутствует, возникает нарушение уникального индекса, выполняется секция ODKU, согласно которой значение поля weight обновляется переданным значением.

Comment: "Создать требуемый индекс" в примере вы создали индекс idx_mat_usr а для чего он нужен? где используется? внизу вторая функция которая производится вставку но в ней не используется переменная idx_mat_usr

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Этот индекс - уникальный. Он гарантирует, что в таблице не будет двух записей с одним и тем же значением в паре полей индекса. По отдельности - сколько угодно дубликатов в любом поле, но парой - нет. Именно он и используется для определения факта, что в таблицу пытаются вставить запись с парой значений, которая там уже есть. Это приводит к ошибке дублирования при попытке вставить, но на такую ошибку в запросе прописана реакция в виде обновления именно той записи, которая и вызвала ошибку дублирования.

Comment: второй шаг остался для меня совсем непонятным.. на первом шаге я зашел в phpmyadmin открыл свою таблицу и в разделе "структура" галками отметил поля, по которым буду сравнивать, и нажал на кнопку "уникальный" получил такой ответ: `ALTER TABLE 'task_kanban_sort' ADD UNIQUE( 'pageid', 'taskid', 'uid');` наверное все прошло успешно_))

А как все-таки средствами php за один запрос вставить данные в таблицу? в вашем ответе я увидел как вставляется только один элемент массива. А что делать если массив многомерный, неужели использовать foreach?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов *в вашем ответе я увидел как вставляется только один элемент массива.* Я, конечно, извиняюсь, но чем Вы смотрите? закомментированную строку видите? смысл её понимаете? похоже, что нет... так вот - давайте-ка понимайте. А элементов туда можно напихать сколько угодно - в пределах максимально допустимой длины текста запроса. Который и по дефолту не сказать что маленький.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз на комментарий не обратил внимание. не понял его смысл)) теперь все встало на свои места, получилось)))

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример решения вашей задачи.

В примере подразумевается, что:

- для доступа к базе используется расширение PDO (с установленным атрибутом `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`), которое выбрасывает исключения в случае возникновения ошибок
- название целевой таблицы - `foobar`
- поле ID целевой таблицы имеет атрибуты `int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`
- Обработка выброшенных исключений, в данном примере, опущена - только суть

```
<?php
$data = array(
    ...
);

function isExists($data)
{
    global $dbh;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `foobar` WHERE uid=:uid AND nid=:nid");
    $sth->execute(array(':uid' => $data['uid'], ':nid' => $data['nid']));
    return $sth->rowCount !== 0;
}

function update($data)
{
    global $dbh;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `foobar` SET weight=:weight WHERE uid=:uid AND nid=:nid");
    $sth->execute(array(':uid' => $data['uid'], ':nid' => $data['nid'], ':weight' => $data['weight']));
}

function insert($data)
{
    global $dbh;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `foobar` (uid, nid, weight) VALUES (:uid, :nid, :weight)");
    $sth->execute(array(':uid' => $data['uid'], ':nid' => $data['nid'], ':weight' => $data['weight']));
}

//$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (itemIsExists($row)) {
        updateItem($row);
    } else {
        insertItem($row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой смысл делать два запроса, когда можно один? Какой смысл делать на клиенте с данными то, что можно сделать на сервере БД?

Comment: @Akina Покажите, как можно реализовать это средствами sql?

Comment: См. мой комментарий к вопросу. Там указано.

Comment: @Akina я попробывал указать ТС на общий подход решения подобных задач. А конкретно этом случае - да, можно оптимизировать по вашему варианту.

Comment: *общий подход решения подобных задач* Лично я считаю, что общий подход - это "каждый занимается своим делом". В частности, работой с данными занимается сервер баз данных. А PHP только командует этим процессом и поставляет исходные данные.